# populating bean objects from the resultset

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, resultset

I am facing a problem regarding populating bean objects from the resultset.

Description:Resultset contains the result of a stored procedure which is join of 3 tables `B`, `BO`, and `BOV`.

I have 3 POJO's corresponding to tables. The relation between tables is: `B` can have 0 or more `BO`'s, `BO` can have 0 or more `BOV`'s. So totally in resultset I have 162 records, which contain duplicates for `B`.

For example:

```
B  BO   BOV
1  1     1
1  1     2
1  2     1
2  1     1
```

and so on.

Actually there are 10 distinct `B`'s. So II want only 10 `B`'s from the resultset not 162 records. Also II should be able to get corresponding `BO` and `BOV`'s like for `B=1` all values of `BO` and `BOV`'s.

How can I do this? This is pure java logic and cannot change anything for the stored procedure. Just have to process the resultset.

Comment: Maybe its just me... but i think you need to rephrase your question. Its really confusing. Maybe post an example of of the resultset retuned.

Comment: I've formatted it. He wasn't aware of Markdown capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Have a running Map of the resultset here is a possible pseudocode

[pseudo code only... not guaranteed to compile]

```
Map mapofBs = new HashMap();
while(rs.hashNext()) {
    rs.next();
    String bId = rs.getString("columnname for id of b");
    B objectB = mapofBs.get(bId);
    if(objectB == null) {
        objectB = new B();
        //read relevant columns from result set and put into objectB
        mapOfBs.put(bId, objectB)
    }   
    //now onto the boId
    String boId = rs.getString("columnname for id of BO");
    BO objectBO = objectB.getBOForId(boId);
    if(objectBO == null) {
        objectBO = new BO();
        //read relevat columns from result set for objectBO
        objectB.addObjectBO(objectBO);
    }
    String bovID = s.getString("columnname for id of BOV");
    BOV objectBOV = objectBO.getBOVForId(bovId);
    if(objectBOV == null) {
        objectBOV = new BOV();
        //read relevat columns from result set for objectBOV
        objectBO.addObjectBOV(objectBOV);
    }
}
//mapOfBs.keySet() gives you a Set<B> which you are interested in
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query to include a GROUP BY is much the best option.

Comment: He stated that he cannot change anything in the Stored Proc.

Comment: I'm well aware of that but it is still the best answer. It's not unknown for constraints like this to magically disappear once a rationale is produced. The rationale here is that it's trivial in the stored procedure, and very efficient, as against having an obviously inexperienced programmer wrestle with many lines of Java to do the same thing in who knows how inefficient a way.